# Connecting two tables for Deletion

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, `tb_empgrocery` is the parent and `tb_empgroc_master` is the child. Every order of a one costumer saves to the database table- `tb_empgrocery` and then `tb_empgroc_master` computes and output the total of how many items and how much total amount have been ordered by the costumer.

Here's my table for `tb_empgrocery`

```
empgrocID     order_no          date_ordered     item_no  qty_ordered  unit_price   amount
    1     15-09-0000000001  2015-09-16 17:24:36   40933         2         65.00     130.00
    2     15-09-0000000001  2015-09-16 17:24:36   40935        43          4.07     175.01
    3     15-09-0000000001  2015-09-16 17:24:36   40934        23          4.07      93.61
```

And for `tb_empgroc_master`

```
empgrocmstID     order_no          date_ordered     total_items  total_amount  order_status
    1        15-09-0000000001  2015-09-16 17:24:36       3          398.62        Pending
```

As you can see `tb_empgroc_master` computes all items that has been ordered by the costumer form `tb_empgrocery`.   `order_no` connect those two tables

Here's my code for the two tables

```
case "Add":
    $itemno = $_POST['itemno'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $unitprc = $_POST['unitprc'];
    $amt = $_POST['amt'];
    $coopmemid = $_SESSION['kiosk']['is_coopmemID_kiosk'];
    $totamt = 0;
    $totitm = count($itemno);
    $a_empgroid = array();
    for($x=0; $x<$totitm; $x++) {
        $Addquery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgrocery (coopmemID , date_ordered, item_no, qty_ordered, unit_price, amount) 
                    VALUES ('$coopmemid',(NOW()),'$itemno[$x]','$qty[$x]','$unitprc[$x]','$amt[$x]')";
        $atecCoop->query($Addquery);
        $totamt+=$amt[$x];
        $inserted_id = $atecCoop->insert_id;
        array_push($a_empgroid,$inserted_id);
    }
    $Savequery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgroc_master (order_status, date_ordered, total_items, total_amount) VALUES ('Pending', (NOW()), '$totitm', '$totamt')";
    $atecCoop->query($Savequery);
    $empgrocmstid = $atecCoop->insert_id;
    $orderno = date('y-m-').str_pad($empgrocmstid, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $sql = "UPDATE tb_empgroc_master SET order_no='$orderno' WHERE empgrocmstID='$empgrocmstid'";
    $atecCoop->query($sql);
    foreach($a_empgroid as $empgrocid) {
        $sql = "UPDATE tb_empgrocery SET order_no='$orderno' WHERE empgrocID='$empgrocid'";
        $atecCoop->query($sql);
    }
break;
```

Here's my Delete query...

```
case "Delete":
    $Deletequery = "CREATE TRIGGER update_tb_empgrocery AFTER UPDATE ON tb_empgrocery FOR EACH ROW
                    BEGIN
                        UPDATE tb_empgroc_master
                        INNER JOIN
                        (
                            SELECT order_no, SUM(amount) AS total_amount, COUNT(empgrocID) AS total_items
                            FROM tb_empgrocery
                            GROUP BY order_no
                        )
                            SET tb_empgroc_master.total_items = tb_empgrocery.total_items,
                            tb_empgroc_master.total_amount = tb_empgrocery.total_amount
                            WHERE tb_empgroc_master.order_no = NEW.order_no;

                            DELETE FROM tb_empgroc_master WHERE empgrocmstID='".$_POST['empgrocmstID']."';

                    END;
                    DELIMITER";
    $atecCoop->query($Deletequery);
```

My problem is when I delete one item in `tb_empgrocery`, tb_empgroc_master doesn't update. It must update the `total_items` which it will become value of 2 and also `total_amount` (if I deleted one of those items in `tb_empgrocery`).

Thanks for your help.

PHP code

```
<?php
    if(!session_id()){
        session_start();
    }
    include_once '../fileadmin/dbinit.php';
    $todo = $_POST['todo'];
//    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","","atec_coop");
//    if (!$con){
//        die("Can't connect".mysql_error());
//    }
    mysql_select_db("atec_coop",$con);
    switch ($todo) {
        case "display":
            $sql = "SELECT * from tb_empgroc_master";
//            $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
            $result = $atecCoop->query($sql);
//            mysql_close($con);

            $html = ''; $ctr = 0;
            if ($result->num_rows){
                while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                $id = $row->empgrocmstID;
                $date_ordered = date("m-d-Y");
                $order_no = date($row->order_no);
                $total_items = number_format($row->total_items);
                $total_amount = number_format($row->total_amount,2);
                $order_status = wordwrap($row->order_status);
                $Order = $row->empgrocmstID;

                $html .= "<tr id='$id'>";
                $html .= "<td class='date_ordered' style='text-align:center'>$date_ordered</td>";
                $html .= "<td class='order_no' style='text-align:center'>$order_no</td>";
                $html .= "<td class='total_items' style='text-align:right'>$total_items</td>";
                $html .= "<td class='total_amount' style='text-align:right'>$total_amount</td>";
                $html .= "<td id='$Order' class='order_status' style='text-align:center'>$order_status</td>";
                $html .= "</tr>";
                }
            }
            echo $html;
        break;
        case "Cancel":
            $Cancelquery = "UPDATE tb_empgroc_master SET order_status='Cancelled' WHERE empgrocmstID='".$_POST['empgrocmstID']."'";
            $atecCoop->query($Cancelquery);
        break;
        case "ApprovePartial":
            $sql = "SELECT * from tb_empgroc_master";
//            $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
            $result = $atecCoop->query($sql);
//            mysql_close($con);

            $html = ''; $ctr = 0;
            if ($result->num_rows){
                while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                $id = $row->empgrocmstID;
                $date_ordered = date("m-d-Y");
                $order_no = date($row->order_no);
                $total_items = number_format($row->total_items);
                $total_amount = number_format($row->total_amount,2);
                $order_status = wordwrap($row->order_status);
                $Order = $row->empgrocmstID;

                $html .= "<tr id='$id'>";
                $html .= "<td class='date_ordered' style='text-align:center'>$date_ordered</td>";
                $html .= "<td class='order_no' style='text-align:center'>$order_no</td>";
                $html .= "<td class='total_items' style='text-align:right'>$total_items</td>";
                $html .= "<td class='total_amount' style='text-align:right'>$total_amount</td>";
                $html .= "<td id='$Order' class='order_status' style='text-align:center'>$order_status</td>";
                $html .= "</tr>";
                }
            }
            echo $html;

            $ApprovePartialquery = "UPDATE tb_empgroc_master SET order_status='Partially Delivered' WHERE empgrocmstID='".$_POST['empgrocmstID']."'";
            $atecCoop->query($ApprovePartialquery);
        break;
        case "Approve":
            $Approvequery = "UPDATE tb_empgroc_master SET order_status='Delivered' WHERE empgrocmstID='".$_POST['empgrocmstID']."'";
            $atecCoop->query($Approvequery);
        break;
        case "Delete":
            $Deletequery = "DELETE FROM tb_empgroc_master WHERE empgrocmstID='".$_POST['empgrocmstID']."'";
            $atecCoop->query($Deletequery);
        break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry but this is a bad database design. If you need `total_items` and `total_amount` use SQL to get that from all the child rows dynamically. Doing as you are doing always makes the process you are talking about a major nightmare, mainly because **you can never totally ensure that these total fields in the master will be properly maintained** So the simple answer is dont keep running totals in a master record!

Comment: Not only `total_items` and `total_amount`. What if I delete all the items from the first table. the second table must be deleted also. How?

Comment: You may not even need to store a `total_items` and `total_amount`. Every time you update `tb_empgrocery` you will need SQL to calculate these values (as @RiggsFolly suggested), which makes you question whether it is more efficient to just run these queries when you want these values, negating the need to store them.

Comment: Is your database MYISAM or INNODB??

Comment: Any suggestions or a helpful comment? I don't need commenting or getting me wrong. Better if you'll teach me, not just to say something that Im doing wrong. I'm new in programming.

Comment: There are reasons for and against keeping these values pre calculated as you are doing so. It might be easiest to do the calculation using a trigger in MySQL (rather than trying to manually do it in php - which will mean the totals are not updated if someone manually amends the data in the database rather than using your scripts).

Comment: Then you could use _triggers_ to maintain the totals and _cascaded deletes_ to make sure child rows were deleted when a master was deleted. See [Trigger Syntax and Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) and [InnoDB and FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) _But I still maintain its simpler and more reliable to redesign the database._

Comment: Can someone help me to update tb_empgroc_master please.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports triggers. These are functions that you can write that are executed when a record is inserted / updated / deleted. You would need one of each.

You would use something like this example for a trigger to be fired when a record is updated on *tb_empgrocery*, and which then updates the figures on the master table for that order.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_tb_empgrocery` AFTER UPDATE ON `tb_empgrocery` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE tb_empgroc_master a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT order_no, SUM(amount) AS total_amount, COUNT(empgrocID) AS total_items
        FROM tb_empgrocery
        GROUP BY order_no
    ) b
    SET a.total_items = b.total_items, 
    a.total_amount = b.total_amount
    WHERE a.order_no = NEW.order_no;
  END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Note that few people use them, and this potentially leads to problems. If there is an issue with the code in future it is likely to be something most people will not even think to check.

EDIT

Here is the code to create the 3 triggers required. The first line *DELIMITER //* just changes the default delimiter from a ; to //. This is so that each line is not executed as a statement when it is created, but instead treated as code to create the trigger functions.

Firstly to create a trigger that is fired off when an existing record on tb_empgrocery is updated

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `update_tb_empgrocery` AFTER UPDATE ON `tb_empgrocery` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE tb_empgroc_master a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT order_no, SUM(amount) AS total_amount, COUNT(empgrocID) AS total_items
        FROM tb_empgrocery
        GROUP BY order_no
    ) b
    ON a.order_no = b.order_no
    SET a.total_items = COALESCE(b.total_items, 0), 
    a.total_amount = COALESCE(b.total_amount, 0)
    WHERE a.order_no = NEW.order_no;
  END;
```

Next to create a trigger that is fired off when a new record inserted onto tb_empgrocery.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_tb_empgrocery` AFTER INSERT ON `tb_empgrocery` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE tb_empgroc_master a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT order_no, SUM(amount) AS total_amount, COUNT(empgrocID) AS total_items
        FROM tb_empgrocery
        GROUP BY order_no
    ) b
    ON a.order_no = b.order_no
    SET a.total_items = COALESCE(b.total_items, 0), 
    a.total_amount = COALESCE(b.total_amount, 0)
    WHERE a.order_no = NEW.order_no;
  END;
```

Lastly to create a trigger that is fired off when an existing record on tb_empgrocery is deleted.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_tb_empgrocery` AFTER DELETE ON `tb_empgrocery` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE tb_empgroc_master a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT order_no, SUM(amount) AS total_amount, COUNT(empgrocID) AS total_items
        FROM tb_empgrocery
        GROUP BY order_no
    ) b
    ON a.order_no = b.order_no
    SET a.total_items = COALESCE(b.total_items, 0), 
    a.total_amount = COALESCE(b.total_amount, 0)
    WHERE a.order_no = OLD.order_no;
  END;
```

Comment: This is a valid concept, **but** I still maintain it is all engineering to compensate for an initial database design fault. The more mitigating engineering you do the more complex the environment is and the more likely that something will go wrong, and the harder it is to fix any issues that may happen with this data.

Comment: Fully agree in theory, but denormalisation is a perfectly valid thing to do for efficiency reasons at times. Whether in this case that is true we cannot tell, but potentially calculating these totals a very large number of times each time an order is viewed rather than once when it is created can slow things down dramatically.

Comment: What is a, b and update_tb_empgrocery? Can I copy this code?

Comment: can you explain to me what is `NEW.order_no?` and `update
_tb_empgrocery`

Comment: a and b are alias names. a is an alias for tb_empgroc_master while b is an alias for the sub query. update_tb_empgrocery is the name of the trigger that this is create. Triggers are fired off when something happens to a table (such as an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE of a record). NEW.order_no refers to the updated value for the order_no field.

Comment: Can you please check my Delete query?

Comment: You don't need to manually execute this trigger each time you delete a record. Rather the code I have given is to create a trigger function on the database. Once it has been created it will be called every time the table has a record inserted / updated / deleted (as appropriate).

Comment: Do I have to create a table `update_tb_empgrocery`? and I don't know what will I put on b. Or Do I have to change your code? or just copy it all?

Comment: And also NEW, do I have to change it also?

Comment: Just copy it (you might need to add a delimiter at the start). But I strongly suggest you read up on triggers before proceeding. b is not a table and you do not need to put anything on it, it is just an alias for the sub query. You do not change NEW, it is just a value that is available (like a global variable).

Comment: Last question please.. Where will I put that code you gave? In my case display? please see my edited question in my `PHP code`

Comment: It doesn't go in the php at all. The code is executed directly once on the database (in phpmyadmin, or whatever else you use to access the database directly), and that creates the trigger. Once created that trigger is  automatically called by MySQL every time a row on the table tb_empgrocery is updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89891/discussion-between-micaela-and-kickstart).